# How to have two event loops?

Tags: python, pyside

I'm making a GUI IRC client in Python using PySide and this IRC library (https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/irc). PySide has a main loop to process GUI events. The IRC library also has a loop to process IRC events. Both loops block after called. What should I do? Is it just running them in different threads?

Comment: Yes you have to run them in different threads.

Comment: It's possible that one or both of your event loop APIs has an alternative interface that you can use, to explicitly poll for events. Then you can have one loop poll the other for events as needed. You may need to have this done on a timer, so that a long eventless stretch for one library won't add too much latency to the other. I'm not sufficiently familiar with PySide or your IRC library to give any specifics, but it would be worth checking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IRC` client class supports external main loop integration through the `on_connect`, `on_disconnect` and `on_schedule` parameters.  In PySide you would use these to create a `QSocketNotifier`, destroy it, and set a `QTimer` respectively:

```
class PySideIRCClient(IRC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket_notifiers = {}
        return IRC(self.on_connect, self.on_disconnect, self.on_schedule)

    def on_connect(self, socket):
        notifier = QtCore.QSocketNotifier(socket, QtCore.QSocketNotifier.Read)
        notifier.activated.connect(self.socket_activated)
        self.socket_notifiers[socket] = notifier

    def socket_activated(self, socket):
        self.process_data([socket])

    def on_disconnect(self, socket):
        self.socket_notifiers[socket].setEnabled(False)
        del self.socket_notifiers[socket]

    def on_schedule(self, seconds):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(seconds * 1000, self.process_timeout)
```

The `PySideIRCClient` is then integrated with the PySide Qt event loop, so you can just use `QtGui.QApplication.exec_()`.

Comment: If my main application is derived from `QtGui.QApplication`, how can I integrate `PySideIRCClient` with my application then?

Comment: @Jellyflower just use `myApp.exec_()` as you would normally; the `QtCore.QSocketNotifier` integrates with the Qt main loop behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The `IRCServer` from that client is a derivative class from `TCPServer`, which is the one providing the `serve_forever` method that starts the loop. There's an alternative method, `handle_request`, that will handle a single request (if there's any).

`serve_forever` does basically that, in a loop (it actually calls a lower level method). You can set `QTimer` to poll the IRCserver, eg. every 0.5 seconds (the default for `serve_forever`). Set also a timeout of 0 for the server, to avoid ending up locked and you're done.